# Rubber ring near sway bar bushing

Tags: seat, bushing, swaybar

I have noticed a rubber ring just before my swaybar bushing. The ring is badly damaged and needs replacing - however, I have no idea what it is called and thus cannot find a replacement.

Could anyone tell me what the rubber ring (picture below, arrow) is called? Thanks.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What vehicle is this. If we know the specifics, we can look it up to see for sure.

Comment: It's a Seat Ibiza S 1.4 16V from 2005. I don't think this part is standard, haven't seen it while reading any literature related to the vehicle.

Answer (score 3):

That looks to be like a broken lateral swaybar lock. It's supposed to keep the sway bar from moving side-to-side through the bushing (so that its only motion is torsional).

You tend to see this in the aftermarket for increasing suspension performance, like [here](http://www.energysuspensionparts.com/universal-sway-bar-lateral-locks.asp).

Comment: You're right. Detail in the pic didn't lend to me seeing it. Deleting my answer as such. +1 and good catch.

Comment: I believe you are correct - thanks! I have somehow never heard of them before. I cannot find a part number - you may be right about them being aftermarket. I may buy a set and replace both sides soon :)

Comment: Its a sway bar bushing, not a lock.